# ROS Groovy joy-stcik 404 error [SOLVED]

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, joystick, joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

SOLVED

Had to clean my update list on my ubunutu install, somehow it had become corrupted. Cleaning that up and attempting "sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-joystick-drivers" again worked perfectly fine

Henry

Hey

I am trying to install ROS joy for ROS Groovy

After saying yes to install the package it fails to fetch the files "Failed to fetch http:\... 404 not found error".

I am using "sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-joystick-drivers" to install.

Is their an updated wiki about how to install ROS joy on groovy that I have missed?

Thanks heaps

Henry

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59169/ros-groovy-joy-stcik-404-error-%5Bsolved%5D/) by [HenryW](https://answers.ros.org/users/3316/henryw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2013-03-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2013-03-26**:
You should place the solution below as the answer for the question.

**Comment by [HenryW](https://answers.ros.org/users/3316/henryw/) on 2013-03-26**:
Sorry have updated now, did not see it down there :D thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Had to clean my update list on my ubunutu install, somehow it had become corrupted. Cleaning that up and attempting "sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-joystick-drivers" again worked perfectly fine

---

Originally posted by [HenryW](https://answers.ros.org/users/3316/henryw/) with karma: 140 on 2013-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0